# Kendo grid refresh (databound twice)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem while refreshing the kendo grid, for some reason, the `dataBound` event is activated twice, does someone know what could be the problem? or is this a normal behavior?

```js
$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

**UPDATE:**

if i remove the refresh line, the `dataBound` happens only once

```js
$("#grid").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```

Comment: Why do you need to call refresh()?

Comment: all examples show the grid refresh using this code, but just now i see the event run twice, but without refresh works fine

Comment: @LucasKonrath It is because you call `dataSource.read()` and it gets data from remote (or may client-side) so first **Databound** happens, then you call `refresh()` it means bound me again to datasource so second **Databound** happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try to give false to autobind and try again.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-autoBind

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply wanting to update the data, you shouldn't need to call `Refresh()`.  `DataSource.Read()` should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the below lines to:

```
$("#KendoGridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
$("#KendoGridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1);
```

to:

```
$("#KendoGridId").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```